# apache doesn't respond sometimes from outside (but always good in localhost) , and then when I restart apache service it's working

Tags: php, apache, webserver, windows-server-2012-r2

PHP 5.6 Mariadb 10, Apache 2.4 , Windows Server 2012 r2 ,Every things setup correctly.

My PHP script (it is just echo "hello word") is working good, and 
I can see it both on `localhost` and from the internet 
but after a while Apache doesn't respond from outside

And in this case there is no log in access.log 
(but always good in localhost, and I can see localhost IP logged in access.log), And then when i restart Apache service it's work even from outside!

My website has no too much traffic and I didn't use session for my app(it is just simple script!).

Comment: Have you check apache error.log ?

Comment: i did not see anything special .

Comment: Actually there is no logs in this situation no error.log and no access.log it seems there is no apache on the server , I can just see my website in localhost but it is unreachable outside.